# When C-c C-c on a block in my org buffer, it collapses the whole buffer

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings

How to avoid this behaviour? I use Prelude.
If I have a source block I want to evaluate, it will do so, but also it will collapse all the headings in the buffer, which is annoying.
Thanks for any help provided!

Comment: What is `C-c C-c` bound to? Do `C-h c C-c C-c` to  find out. It should be bound to `org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c` - if that's the case for you, you should try starting with `emacs -q` and, assuming that that works, then bisect your init file to see who does the damage.

Comment: Thanks. It is indeed bound to org-ctrl-c-ctr-c and emacs -q works fine. So I'll have to see what causes this behaviour.